# Wrapping multiple TextBoxes into a DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, webforms

I have a web page and my in my data access layer I am updating the textboxes to my page. It is a simple 3 Tier App.

Something like this I have in my DataAccess Class:

```
 public void SaveDataSet(DataTable table)
        {

           //What to do here???

        }
```

How should I pass all of my textboxes value to this function as DataTable parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or if you want to go the data table way yo need something like this

first we create the datatable

```
private DataTable CreateDataTable()
{
DataTable myDataTable = new DataTable();

DataColumn myDataColumn; 

myDataColumn = new DataColumn();
myDataColumn.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
myDataColumn.ColumnName = "id";
myDataTable.Columns.Add(myDataColumn);

myDataColumn = new DataColumn();
myDataColumn.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
myDataColumn.ColumnName = "username";
myDataTable.Columns.Add(myDataColumn);

myDataColumn = new DataColumn();
myDataColumn.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
myDataColumn.ColumnName = "firstname";
myDataTable.Columns.Add(myDataColumn);

myDataColumn = new DataColumn();
myDataColumn.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
myDataColumn.ColumnName = "lastname";
myDataTable.Columns.Add(myDataColumn);

return myDataTable;
}
```

then you need a method to insert data to your datatable

```
private void AddDataToTable(string username,string firstname,string lastname,DataTable myTable)
{
DataRow row;

row = myTable.NewRow();

row["id"] = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
row["username"] = username;
row["firstname"] = firstname;
row["lastname"] = lastname;

myTable.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

now you can create a method to insert the datatable to the sql server like this

```
private void insertDataTable(DataTable MyDataTable)
        {
            string ConnectionString = "your connection string";
            using (SqlBulkCopy bulkcopy = new SqlBulkCopy(ConnectionString)
            {
                bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = “dbo.<your table>”;
                try
                {
                    bulkcopy.WriteToServer(MyDataTable);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
              }
          }
```

Comment: Oh! My....I just read Entity Model Framework and I knew this is happening. Thanks for the info. I am learning as fast as I can...

Comment: Don't mention it :) Im really pleased with EF its awesome

Comment: Also i would recommend you to step into ASP MVC 3 it just blends pretty good with Entity Framework

Comment: Yea, I started learning MVC3 using Entity Framework. It is pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use Microsoft Entity Framework, you can grab some video tutorials  [here](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials) it is pretty easy to use and really fast, and it will not take you too much on understand how it works, also it [googles](http://www.google.com.mx/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=entity+framework+asp.net) really well ;)